# Pandas: How to convert rows into one string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame that I want to convert into a concatenated string after iterating through but with each on new line.

Input:

```
    str_col
0      This
1        is
2       one
3  sentence
```

Output:

```
This
is
one
sentence
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"str_col" : ["This", "is", "one", "sentence"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Just print the output as strings? just print (df) will give you the output. Not sure what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ankit. Is it possible to convert just one column into the output shown above using `to_string()`?

Comment: There isn't a column now. It's just a string. It doesnt have any structure.

Comment: I just checked the documentation, and the following works for me.
`df.to_string(columns=["str_col"], header=False, index=False, index_names=False)`